# How to add menuitems from a listbox Vb.net/C#

Tags: vb.net

I have two listboxes: the first one adds the mainmenuitem like File, Edit etc...
The second adds the submenuitems like open,new etc

When I want two add the submenus I select the menuitem from the first listbox and then choose from the second listbox what to add...

The problem is i get this error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem'.

The code

```
Dim val As MenuItem
val = ListBox1.SelectedItem
val.MenuItems.Add(TextBox2.Text)
```

This is the code for the second listbox. The first one works fine and add the menuitems like it should.

Please help Im going mad.

Comment: Please show us the code, where you fill ListBox1

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBox1.SelectedItem` returns an object (can be a string even).
It is not a MenuItem.
`

Comment: You can look here: [ListBox.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx)
May be it will help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new MenuIten within the add function.

```
val.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(TextBox2.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in this line:

```
 val = ListBox1.SelectedItem
```

`val` is `MenuItem` as you declared in `Dim val As MenuItem`, but `ListBox1.SelectedItem` is an object

Moreover this line:

```
val.MenuItems.Add(TextBox2.Text)
```

you should replace with:

```
val.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(TextBox2.Text))
```

Comment: `ListBox1.SelectedItem` is an `Object`, not a `string`, isn't it?

Comment: Replaced the line of code and also fixed the variable declaration its a object now. Now i get a new error. Public member 'MenuItems' on type 'String' not found.

Comment: This means that after `val = ListBox1.SelectedItem` val is a `string` not a `ListBox`. why are you trying to add `MenuItem` to `SelectedItem`

Comment: How must I use it then so that in can work, I'm still new to programming, my first year programing now.

Comment: `SelectedItem` is what you choose in ListBox. It is not another `ListBox`. I do not know what you are trying to do. If you have another `ListBox` add `MenuItem ` to it.